# Should I use "whereas" or "while" in this sentence?

Tags: conjunctions

Are the both sentences below correct? A friend of mine claims that it's not possible to use **whereas** for this expression. When I look for their difference I could only see that we shouldn't use **whereas** for expressions with time.

> Freedom is a slippery concept, and  **whereas** we may casually use the word with some frequency, it is difficult to arrive at a precise definition **that** is agreeable to most of us.
>
> Freedom is a slippery concept, and  **while** we may casually use the word with some frequency, it is difficult to arrive at a precise definition **which** is agreeable to most of us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either is fine, and in this usage, *whereas* and *while* are synonyms. It is also true that the more literal sense of *while*—meaning "during the same period of time as"—cannot be expressed using *whereas*.